# how to make intellij tab key function like eclipse tab key does

Tags: intellij-idea

In eclipse when I press the tab key, it takes the current line to the correct indentation instantly...even if that is 5 tab's in.  So

```
public class TabTest {
  public void func1() {
    int a = 1;
|int b = 2;
```

The '|' pipe being where the cursor is, when I hit tab once it looks correct

```
public class TabTest {
  public void func1() {
    int a = 1;
   |int b = 2;
```

In intellij I have to hit tab twice.  Or here is another annoyance.

```
public class TabTest {
  public void func1() {
    int a = 1;|int b = 2;
```

In eclipse 'Enter' will result in

```
public class TabTest {
  public void func1() {
    int a = 1;
   |int b = 2;
```

In Intellij that takes an enter, tab, tab.

Anyone know how to get what i had in eclipse into intellij?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From CrazyCoder comment, the solution seems to be :

- map the tab key on the "Auto-indent Lines" action
- unmap the tab key from the "Tab" and "Indent Selection" actions

Comment: This doesn't work for blank lines; instead, it moves the cursor to the following line.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with either your IDEA installation or the settings. Indentation works automatically on <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you don't have to hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> at all.

Try running with all the default settings after renaming IDEA [config directory](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181) and see if you still can reproduce it. Specify your IDEA version and provide sample project with the steps to replicate the problem if the issue persists.

Comment: This is not a configuration problem. With Eclipse in a Java editor, if you press the tab key on the leading blank of a line, the line is indented (if there is some content), and the caret is positioned at the right position for the beginning of the line. In IDEA, if you press Tab while in the leading blank, it tries to tabulate... so to reproduce the behaviour of the Tab key in IDEA on a line with content you have to: shift+right, delete, shift+left, backspace (removes the leading blank + newline), return (reintroduce the new line and indents)

Comment: If your goal is to fix the indentation of the current line, use Code | Auto-Indent Lines (Ctrl+Alt+I), it also works for selection so you can indent multiple lines.

Comment: Fix the indentation and place the caret at the beginning of the content, that's what the poster was asking for yes.